# Ingress routing misses prefix for django redirects

Tags: django, http, redirect, kubernetes-ingress

I deployed a Django app in a K8s cluster and have some issues with the routing by Ingress.

**Ingress config:**

```
apiVersion: projectcontour.io/v1
kind: HTTPProxy
metadata:
  name: main
  namespace: ${namespace}
spec:
  routes:
    - conditions:
        - prefix: /my-app
      services:
        - name: my-app-backend
          port: 80
      timeoutPolicy:
        response: 60s
  pathRewritePolicy:
    replacePrefix:
      - replacement: /
```

**my-app/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import include, path
from overview import views

app_name = "overview"

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index),
    path("overview", views.overview)
    ...
]
```

I have a url like `example.com` where the paths are redirected to several K8s services.

URL `example.com/my-app/` should be resolved to my service `my-app`. So far so good, I can see the entry page of my app.

But if I start clicking buttons from here, the relative redirects done by Django are not working as expected:

A Button click which is expected to navigate me to `example.com/my-app/overview`,
targets to `example.com/overview` which results in 404 obviously.

I would expect a `/my-app/` prefix for all redirects in `my-app`. I'm an Ingress rookie, but I would assume that `my-app` shouldn't be responsible for this information, as I would have to change two repos when the domain path changes eventually (and I want to avoid routers or hardcoding the url prefixed to `/my-app/`).

Can I achieve this expected behavior with Ingress, or whats the best practice here?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm an Ingress rookie, but i would assume that my-app shouldn't be responsible for this information, as I would have to change two repos when the domain path changes eventually (and i want to avoid routers or hardcoding the url prefixed to /my-app/).

This is not an application task. You rightly said that it should be taken care of by ingress. Your ingress is not configured properly. First look at the [official documentation](https://projectcontour.io/docs/v1.12.0/config/request-rewriting/):

> If a `prefix` field is present, the replacement is applied only to routes that have an exactly matching prefix condition

In a situation where you want to open `example.com/my-app/overview` , you are redirected to `example.com/overview`, because `my-app` was replaced by `/`. It looks like you don't need to change the paths at all.

But if you want to change your yaml a bit, take the following as an example and adapt it to your needs by providing the appropriate prefixes and replacements.

```yaml
apiVersion: projectcontour.io/v1
kind: HTTPProxy
metadata:
  name: rewrite-example
  namespace: default
spec:
  virtualhost:
    fqdn: rewrite.bar.com
  routes:
  - services:
    - name: s1
      port: 80
    conditions:
    - prefix: /v1/api
    pathRewritePolicy:
      replacePrefix:
      - prefix: /v1/api
        replacement: /app/api/v1
      - prefix: /
        replacement: /app
```

> If no `prefix` field is present, the replacement is applied to all prefix matches made against the route. If a `prefix` field is present, the replacement is applied only to routes that have an exactly matching prefix condition. Specifying more than one `replacePrefix` entry is mainly useful when a HTTPProxy document is included into multiple parent documents.